# wpf remove datagrid left padding

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

Can somebody please shed some light on how to get rid of the mysterious padding on the left?
I've tried numerous properties but none seem to affect.

[image: Padding on the left]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The padding you are referring to is probably the row header.  To remove the row headers, you can set `HeadersVisibility="Column"` on the `DataGrid`.

I have seen cases where even with this property set to "Column" some of the rows still show a header.  You can work around this by setting `RowHeaderWidth="0"` on the `DataGrid`.

Comment: I globally set the `HeadersVisibility="Column"` and it worked like a charm! Thanks.. :)

Comment: it worked thank you !! RowHeaderWidth="0" without this it didnt work for me correctly.. stange issue...

Answer (score 2):

I cannot say where the extra padding is because you haven't provided any code. It might be somewhere in the style of the grid.

In such cases the Snoop utility can be very useful: http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons for this. Either the Template you are using has defined some setter property for the GridviewColoums or the GridViewColumns may be inheriting some settings defined in App.xaml or may be because of some settings in Theme (incase you are using one)